# Possible to specify a file of cypher commands with neo4j-shell-tools?

Tags: neo4j

I want to use the neo4j-shell-tools https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools because my desired output is a CSV file.  With a single Cypher command, this works great, e.g.,

```
neo4j restart
neo4j-shell

import-cypher -o out.csv match (p) return count(p) as count
```

However, I actually have a large number of cypher commands saved in a .cql file that I'd like to run.  So long as I don't want to export as a CSV file, I can do so via

```
neo4j-shell -file neatStuff.cql
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to combine these, that is, using `import-cypher` to export the results of a file's worth of Cypher commands.

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how it would be best done?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using multiple commands is not an issue, you can use a pipe. This works on both Unix-based and Windows systems.

```
echo 'import-cypher -o out.csv match (p) return count(p) as count' | bin/neo4j-shell
neo4j-shell -file neatStuff.cql
```

**Note:** the [openCypher style guide](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/docs/style-guide.adoc#3-recommendations) recommends the `.cypher` extensions. If you would like to keep is short, use `.cyp` as `.cql` is the extensions for the Cassandra Query Language.

**Update:** as pointed out by the OP in the comments, the latest version of [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) provides `apoc.export.csv.*` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I also note that the (very?) new version 3.0.4.3 of the  APOCs contains apoc.export.csv.*, which looks like it may provide another way to do this.  I haven't experimented at length with it though.